# Define vector of vector of classes and call it from inside a function

Tags: c++

I have some problem with pointers, I think that those are standard problems, but nether the less I was unable to solve them...

My difficulties are to define vector of vector of a class (*`CRegression`*) and initialized it to *`num_bits`* vector elements and in each one of them one element of *`CRegression`* (*`CRegression`* need *`num_mesurments`* as initialization parameter). Second, how could i call the element R2 from class *`CRegression`* in the function `solve_regression`.

I hope that the following example will explains why I need *`b`* as a pointer.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint<
#include <Eigen/Core>

typedef Eigen::Matrix< double , Eigen::Dynamic , 1 >    VectorXd;
typedef Eigen::Matrix< double , 1              , 1 >    Scalard;

void solve_regression( std::queue<double> *b , double &CReg_index , 
                       std::vector<CRegression> &Reg ) {
      std::cout << "size of b" << (*b).size()       << std::endl;
      std::cout << "R2" <<  (*Reg[CReg_index]).R2[0]  << std::endl;

      VectorXd::Map( &(*b).front() , (*b).size() );
}

class CRegression {

public:
CRegression( uint32_t  num_mesurments );
    Scalard        R2;

private:

};


int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

      uint8_t num_bits = 20;
      std::vector<double> CReg_index(num_bits,0);
      std::vector< std::queue<double> > b(num_bits);
      // The next line does not pass compilation (why?)
      std::vector< std::vector<CRegression> >   Reg( num_bits ,
                   std::vector<CRegression>(1,CRegression(50) ) );

      for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < num_bits ; i++ )
          solve_regression( &(b[i]) ,  CReg_index[i] , &(Reg[i]) );

}
```

Comment: Please post the error that you mention occurs at compilation, to save us (the readers) guessing.

Comment: Off-topic: does anyone know the name of the font that SO is currently using for code snippets, comment boxes, etc? I like it!

Comment: That line doesn't contain any compilation errors.  However, there are several other compilation errors in your code.  Is your question really just "please fix my compiler errors"?

Comment: @Marlon, try https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/font-finder/ - if that doesn't help, ask on meta :)

Answer (score 0):

> I hope that the following example will explains why i need *b* as a pointer.

You don't need *b* as a pointer. Use a reference argument.

Comment: `VectorXd::Map( &(*b).front() , (*b).size() );` need the start address of `b`. so i need to pass `b` as a reference, or not?

Comment: @Eagle: with `b` as a reference that expression becomes `VectorXd::Map( &b.front() , b.size() )`.

Answer (score 0):

The marked line compiles fine with g++ 4.5 but the call to solve_regression does not. Make sure the constructor of `CRegression` for `CRegression(50)` is valid. Also please read through https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#pointers-and-references thoroughly and learn how to use references correctly.